# Python 2.7 sublist of nested list not working

Tags: python-2.7, nested-lists, sublist

I am getting some strange results with extracting sublist.

```
list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Switching the first and second index produces the same results.

```
list[:][1]
Out[8]: [4, 5, 6]

list[1][:]
Out[9]: [4, 5, 6]
```

and if I do this, it gives me an error

```
list[0:1][1]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-93d72f916672>", line 1, in <module>
 list[0:1][1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is this some known error with python 2.7?

Comment: A slice is not inclusive of the last number, e.g. `[1, 2, 3][0:1] == [1]` therefore `[1, 2, 3][0:1][1]` will always create an `IndexError` (indexes start at `0`). In your example `lst[0:1] == [[1,2,3]]`, i.e. a list with only `1` item that is a list. Not sure why you are using slices for indexing `[:]` is expensive and unnecessary. Note: don't call your variable `list` it hides python's builtin type.

Comment: Its not [1,2,3] its [[1,2,3]],  both are very different! See my answer for more details

Comment: @RathanNaik I see now, thanks! Is there anyway to slice a column of list? For example, to get a list of the first element of sublists, [1,4,7]?

Comment: Yes there are many ways to do that here is my way,
**list = [ i[0] for i in list ]**

Comment: Let me know if it helps

Comment: @RathanNaik Yes, it does the work, thanks

Comment: @Roy You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you slice a list say 0:5, list will get sliced excluding list[5]

```
Ex : l = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
l = l[0:5]
now l is [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Its same situation here, so its only 0th element present in list that is your list after slice is [[1,2,3]], which means 0th element is [1,2,3] and 1st element is out of range.!

Answer (score 1):

If you observe the [Slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-slice-notation) `list[0:1]`, It creates a list of size one, Also in **Python** indexing starts from **0** therefore, accessing index 1 of list with size one will raise an Error `list index out of range`

```
list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]  //Original List

list[0:1] // [[1,2,3]]   A list of size 1

list[0:1][1] // This will return list index out of range

list[0:1][0]  // [1,2,3]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and direction to the slice post!